# CollabNet SVN Server or VisualSVN?

Tags: svn

I want to set up a **SVN Server** on a Windows 2003 system.

At the moment I am not sure if I should install **CollabNet-SVN** or **VisualSVN**.
I have read, that CollabNet-SVN only provides a command line client for administration and 
that it is a little bit tedious to set it up. VisualSVN comes with a GUI based administration client, which is easy to use.

Therefore I have some questions:

Are there free administration tools (with a GUI) for CollabNet SVN Server ?

Are there short and easy to learn tutorials to use CollabNet SVN ?

Visual SVN installs Apache too ! For CollabNet SVN this is not necessary.
Are there problems, if there is also an active **IIS** on the Windows Server ?

Is it better to use CollabNet SVN with an apache installation ? In my case web access
is not necessary !

Are the capabilities of Visual SVN (Standard Edition) and CollabNet SVN equal ?

Comment: No problem installing apache on the same server as IIS as long as they are both assigned to different tcp ports.

Comment: Maybe better use a distributed VCS (like Bazaar - http://bazaar-vcs.org ). It doesn't need a server.

Comment: @myfreeweb: Subversion doesn't need a server either, if you're not sharing your repository among multiple users.

Comment: @greg-hewgill: DVCS doesn't need a server for sharing a repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual SVN Server indeed has a nice GUI for repository maintenance and setting up access rights. In addition, it also allows you to set access rights using your windows accounts (windows authentication), which can make your life a lot easier.

During my quick tests, I did not find any problems with with IIS due to installing Visual SVN Server (it allows you to use a different port than the standard 443). BTW: Visual SVN Server uses the https:// protocol, whereas with svnserve you could use svn://.

These are the reasons why I will switch to Visual SVN Server soon.

Comment: Note that Windows authentication is severely limited in the Standard Edition of VisualSVN, so it's not really important in this comparison.

Comment: Thanks @mghie! Did this change recently? It's some months since I made some quick tests with it.

Comment: I don't really know, but I'd guess it was never any different - it is just a really convincing thing to get people to spend money on VisualSVN licenses. For multiple users on multiple machines integration with Active Directory is needed, and that requires the paid-for VisualSVN version.

Comment: The free version of VisualSVN server fully supports using Active Directory logins. It just requires the user to enter their credentials (which can be remembered by SVN) instead of using the integrated Windows credentials. Not really a big deal.

Answer (score 6):

As many have mentioned in their answers, Subversion has two major protocols: `http/https` or `svn`.

**svn protocol**

Pro:

- fast
- very simple to setup, no need for 3rd
  party software

Con:

- Simple file based authentication setup

  - So user cannot manage their own password
  - No encryption on password

**http/https protocol**

Pro:

- Support wide range of authentication system, pretty much anything Apache HTTP server support.
- Because of the above, it can be integrated into your company's authentication system like LDAP/ActiveDirectory.
- https protocol can encrypt your communication, if that is a concern.
- Flexibility of connection management, like going through firewall.
- Allow you to browse your repository through web browser

Con:

- <strike>Slower</strike> Much improved in [Subversion 1.7](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#httpv2) release.
- More complicated to manage. Especially if you want fine grain access configurations and serving multiple repositories on the same server.

So depend on what you need, you can pick which protocol suit you best.

We use both protocols at our place, where internally we mostly use `svn` protocol and `http/https` protocol to expose our repository to public.

Answer (score 4):

VisualSVN is limited to `http://` and `https://` protocols.
However, `svn://` protocol is [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372569/subversion-protocol-performance), so I suggest using CollabNet SVN for performance reasons.

Comment: Where in the performance realm?  Check-outs? Commits? Creating repos? UI experience? ...

Comment: Any communication with server (commit, update, blame, etc) is significantly slower. However with release of svn 1.7 performance of http transport is improved, see http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#httpv2

Comment: Both VisualSVN and Collabnet now default to using `http(s)://` via the apache module. But both ship with svnserve.exe if you want to use svn://. I don't think their admin kits will work if you use it.

Answer (score 3):

CollabNet is now CollabNetServerEdge. The main change is it uses Apache instead of svnserve (still included though), and makes it easier to setup. It has a browser based admin console. It also adds features like integrated viewvc for code browsing and ldap authenication. The down side is the windows authentication is very clumsy and will create duplicate accounts if the user isn't careful with the case of the user name. It also doesn't use the security groups from active directory either, so it's a pointless, insecure feature. ViewVC is good for external users or people without an svn client, but we have gotten by without that feature for years.

Another downside of collabnet is importing old repositories requires a dump to import from. I found that the larger repositories can take hours to perform a dump. VisualSVN server only needed to copy the repository.

I like ankhSVN so I started with Collabnet edge, but now I'm leaning towards VisualSVN server.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [CollabNet SVN](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) (use the apache option in the install) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads) as a nice GUI client. I'm not a huge opensource guy but love this combination.

Currently i'm using this in a windows/visual studio 2005+ only environment and 10+ developers

Comment: For me it is imoportant that it is easy to administrate. I don't want to edit config files or use a command line client !

Comment: after that statement I think you have your answer, you should go with VisualSVN

Answer (score 1):

CollabNet works just fine.  I have it running locally on my home development machine as a Windows service.  I use TortoiseSVN to administer my repositories, so there are no worries.

Are you setting this up for yourself or a team?  I don't have experience as an SVN administrator for others.

Comment: I think it is not relevant if it is for a team or only one person !

Comment: I am setting up it for a very small team (4 people)

Comment: My experience is relevant only for one person, so I can't speak for administering it for a team.