# SVN server with Apache or Windows service

Tags: apache, svn

I have to configure SVN server. I am evaluating two approaches

- With Apache.
- Without Apache as a OS(Windows) service.

If I go with Apache, I will have browser level access too, which I consider an added advantage.

What approach should I take ?

Comment: with Apache is best. You could install WebSVN on top of that to have browser level access with DIFF option.

Comment: Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372569/subversion-protocol-performance), also look at the recommendations [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You want apache - your flexibility and options for logging, authentication and authorization are way richer.