# Subversion repository's mapped drive not working using file protocol

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I am new to subversion. I do not have admin skills in subversion. We have set up a subversion repository using Collabnet on machine-1 on C:\csvn\data\repositories .Now I am able to connect to subversion repo with http and file protocol using tortoise client.

I am able to write/commit a file to the subversion repository. No issues.

But now I have shared(full read/write permission) the repositories folder on machine-1. From machine 2 , I have mapped the repositories folder of machine-1 using drive Z:/ .

Now on machine-2 using tortoise client I am able to connect to the file:///Z:/xyz or http:///svn/repositories/xyz etc.

When writing/committing a file using http protocol,it works fine from machine-2, but if I use file protocol, it through exception as follow :

*"Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: The system cannot find the path specified.
Error found in commit
This error was generated by a custom hook script on the subversion server.
Please contact your server administrator for help with resolving this issue."*

Please some can could help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: **Don't** use via shared folders! - [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/372588/1441)

Comment: If you are going to expose your repositories to multiple users, then install Subversion+Apache server to access them via HTTP(S). Don't use `file://` access scheme to access your repos as regular users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Commit blocked by pre-commit hook... The system cannot find the path specified

Pre-commit hook on repository host call some (local for machine-1) program, which doesn't exist on the same path on machine-2 (when you use `file:///`, repository considered as local, and only local resources used on hooks).

Don't use `file:///` on shared drives, it's **THE BAD THING (tm)** for a lot of reasons